# How to get arrow key from socket

Tags: c

I get char from telnet via socket. I don't know how to check if arrow key was pressed.
I have char * buffer, where this message exists

Comment: When you get answers, you should click the check mark (under the answer score) of the answer that correctly solved your problem. This is both to reward the one who helped you and guide future visitors towards the correct solution.

Comment: What sort of terminal is attached to the far end of your socket? Do you know what sequence of bytes it sends when an arrow key is pressed?

Comment: @user1339063 - What twain249 and Shahbaz are trying to say is: Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179533) question and its answer. Doing so is purely at your discretion. If answers do not satisfy you, don't accept them. Good luck!

Comment: I don't; I can not see it on console

Answer (score 2):

There is no Ascii value for the cursor characters on a keyboard - so no standard way to represent them as a char.  In addition telnet doesn't make any assumption about the machine at the other end, it might be a 1950s teletype with no idea of a cursor.

The program sending the message would have to detect the arrow keys using some operating system specific function (ncurses or scancode) and then encode that in some way on the telnet link, typically by sending an escape and then a character to represent each arrow.

A reasonable solution is to assume vt102 codes - the first popular character addressable terminal

edit: see [How do I send an arrow key in Perl using the Net::Telnet module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502197/how-do-i-send-an-arrow-key-in-perl-using-the-nettelnet-module)